# What does ～くて mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, て-form

I've been taught that ～くて is used when linking adjectives, but as I was reading I ran into this sentence :

> それは嘘じゃなくて？

What is exactly the meaning of ～くて in this sentence ? Why isn't it simply じゃない ?

Comment: 上品な言葉づかいの女性のセリフですか？

Comment: そう言えば、キャラクターはメイドだと思います。

Comment: @Ushiromiya If this is language from a manga, maybe you could (tag your question [tag:manga] and) provide more context. As you can see from the comments/answers, depending on the context, this phrase can mean more than one thing.

Comment: It is from a Visual Novel. I see, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two things that play into this

1. You can think of it as some sort of ellipsis (omission):

   > それは嘘じゃなくて、本当ですか？
2. じゃない？ is often used to make a *positive* statement

   > それは嘘じゃない？
   >   *literally* Is that not a lie?
   >   *actual meaning* That's a lie. / That's not true.

So (2) would be a stronger statement than (1). In particular, saying (2) makes you sound you believe the statement to be false whereas saying (1) you are simply wondering whether it could really be true.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. So, in this sentence : それは嘘じゃなくて, they just omitted the end ? Basically, it means : "It's not a lie, right ?"

Comment: If there is no question mark, it could still be seen as an ellipsis, but it would be a shortening of a *statement*, not a question: それは嘘じゃなくて(本当ですよ) = "That's not a lie (but the truth)". Statements and questions are different: "Is this really an apple?" ≠ "This is really an apple."

Comment: I had a COMPLETELY different kind of answer in mind, but I guess the mods should know better.

Comment: @l'électeur There's nothing about mods that helps them answer questions. If you understood the question differently, I'd be interested to hear how (especially since in some cases the OP even accepts an explanation, even if it doesn't answer the question they had in mind).

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is the explanation you provided me an alternate usage of  ～くて ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya No. The point is that, apart from what I said, there is a very particular usage of ～て, which appears as so-called "role language", that is language encountered primarily in fiction. It can be used to characterize a fictional character (upper class lady), just like baby speech could be used for baby/childish characters. You still haven't given enough context to be sure, but if this is not role language (if it's not a maid that consistently uses posh language, or is making fun of posh people, or...), it should probably be interpreted in the way I said.

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain this is a 役割語{やくわりご} in fiction for an elegant, upper-class lady. In this 役割語, not only can the て form be used in questions as in your example, but also statements like this: 絶対{ぜったい}に許さなくて{ゆるさなくて}よ！

Comment: Now that I think of it, the character saying this sentence was a maid. So, does that mean that we shouldn't use this in daily conversation ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya Yes, it would sound pretty weird unless you were joking.

Comment: And what exactly is the purpose of this 役割語 ? How does that change the meaning of a sentence ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya I don't think it changes the meaning; it just makes it more お嬢様っぽい.