# Parsing positive じゃない statements — 体重が増えればいいってことじゃなくて

Tags: grammar

体重が増えればいいってことじゃなくて

As a beginner-intermediate learner, my first reading of the (partial) sentence was along the lines of "it wouldn't be good to gain weight [and]..." but the given translation has an almost opposite meaning with "it's not just that it would be good to gain weight...".

I've been wrestling with this for a while and I think I've gotten my bearings somewhat. The two things confusing me are (1) the positive meaning, and (2) the "not just".

Is it right to say:

(1) it's positive because it uses the "いいじゃない" structure rather than a negatively conjugated "よくない"? It kind of got hazy for me because of the conversational 'ってこと' inserted, but I believe you can essentially ignore that aspect.

(2) is the "just" essentially because of the "なくて"?

So another way to parse the ending of the sentence is something like "wouldn't it *and*..." (because of the rhetorical negative and the -て continuation), but in context of the "it would be good to gain weight" base you can collapse it into "not just" getting you the final meaning?

I feel like I'm close but I'm not quite correctly parsing out the nuanced meaning of the sentence. Like I'm 80% there. Or maybe I'm totally off!

Comment: @ ztom Hi ! Welcome ! Very interesting question I think an answer to your question may be found here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/45043/what-does-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a6-mean-in-this-sentence

Comment: @Makoto thank you twice over! From my understanding, your link confirms the (2) part of my question—I'm mostly left wondering how to consistently recognize positive usages of "じゃない" in a sentence like this, though the answer may just be context (and experience) as it so often is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- AってことじゃなくてB : (it) doesn’t mean A but B
- 体重が増えればいい : it would be fine if you gain weight
- 体重が増えればいいってことじゃなくて : (it) doesn’t mean that you can just gain weight (but ...)

Comment: Interesting!

What follows that line is an example of a benefit of gaining weight (better nutrition)... So, using your points, I think it's literally "It doesn't mean that gaining weight is good [for it's own sake] but also in order to eat more nutritiously" and the translation just took some liberties with a more positive framing for gaining weight because of the proceding listed benefits.

I think I understand now, thank you!