Meaning of て form here: 「あなたどう思って？」と聞いた。
From Kokoro chapter 19:

「あなたどう思って？」と聞いた。「私からああなったのか、それともあなたのいう人世観とか何とかいうものから、ああなったのか。隠さずいって頂戴」

I wonder why 思う is conjugated to て form here.

Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/45046/9831

Yamanote young women in those days used te-form like this:

よろしくって？
Are you okay? / Is this all right?

これは本でして？
Is this a book?

どう思って？
What do you think?

よろしくってよ。
I'm fine. / It's okay.

これは本でしてよ。
This is a book.

そう思いましてよ。
I think so.


This type of speech now remains as part of stereotypical お嬢様言葉 in fiction.

Is this an omission of ん, like some kind of super-contraction?  思っているの > 思っているん > 思ってん > 思って

@istrasci I think these are basically abbreviated forms of something very polite and honorific. I imagine the "base" is something like 思っていらっしゃるのかしら.
